# Trying to see if an element exists

Tags: jquery

Here is the jquery I am testing:

```
var length = $('#showLBVRBVVol').length;
if(length != 0) {
   console.log('test');
}
```

This throw an error of undefined

What is interesting is this works:

```
var length = $('#showLBVRBVVol').length;
if(length == 0) {
   console.log('test');
}
```

The above will correctly log 'test'.  Is there something I am doing wrong that the first option is not working but the second one is?

The element is dynamically added if it is needed otherwise it doesn't exist. I need to be able to tell the difference between the two.

EDITED:

http://jsfiddle.net/d6dZG/

Comment: It is impossible. The code you've shown cannot throw such errors. Please reproduce that on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Let me guess... You are trying out this code in a browser console?

Comment: Correct, surprisingly this works in jsfiddle.

Comment: @zerkms I added the jsfiddle code.

Comment: @James Wilson: I see the correct result: "element found; no element found". Uhm?

Comment: @zerkms Correct, right above that comment I stated interestingly it worked in jsfiddle.  But for some reason the same code does not work in the firebug console.

Comment: @James Wilson: oh, missed that, sorry

Comment: @holodoc Do you know why this works if added to the source, but not in firebug?  That is what threw me off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want check whether it exists or not, so to check existence of `'#showLBVRBVVol'` element

```
if($('#showLBVRBVVol').length) // if true
{
    console.log('exists'); // Output: 'exists' only when if condition is true
}
```

if it exists then it will return 1 (boolean true) otherwise 0 (boolean false)

Comment: This works.  I was confused because the code would not work in Firebug, but it worked if I added it to the source code.

Comment: Hope it's not a confusion anymore !

Comment: I still am not sure why it didn't work in firebug, but does in the source.  I'd like to know that if anyone knows, but other than that I'm just glad it works. :)

Comment: I've tested the same code from my answer in FF and it worked the same way.

Comment: This is correct.  Always use the length attribute to test an element's existence, since jQuery still returns something (an empty array) if no element is found.

Comment: Maybe it was just my version of FF or firebug then.  Ah well, chalking this one up to browser weirdness.  Thanks for all the help everyone!